# How to hide objects outside artboards in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

Is it possible to hide the objects that are outside of the artboard?

As you can see in the picture below, the polygons are shown outside of the artboard.

I want to hide everything that is outside of the artboard.

[image: Objects visible outside the artboard]

Comment: Use a clipping mask

Comment: Apparently, the only solutions are workarounds. Strange that it can't be done natively. Or is it a nudge to think creatively?

Answer (score 24):

Go to: View > Trim View
Can toggle on and off through menu, or create your own keystroke shortcut.

Comment: This answer is super-short, but essentially correct; however it's ***only*** applicable to someone running the *very latest build* of Illustrator CC (23.0 +), and so may not help anyone who's not - for those on older versions, there are other answers which may help more.

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE! Please explain better, for example by adding an screenshot (?)

Comment: He's right... it was in front of us the whole time.

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 21):

I usually just create a rectangle with no fill and the heaviest stroke possible (1000pt). Then align the stroke to outside. Then I change the line colour to match the grey background. Set this as the top layer and you can easily toggle it on and off, or lock the layer and simply work around it. Way easier than messing around with clipping masks.

Comment: Basically the same method as my answer... but easier +1

Comment: This should be the selected answer. I've been using Illustrator since 1995 and I have never found an easier way to hide overflowing artwork.

Answer (score 16):

Using a clipping mask is one option, but can be annoying if you want to keep the mask while you are working with the ability to turn it on and off.

This may not be the best option but is what I sometimes do.

1. Create a new layer above all your other layers

[image: Create a new layer]

2. Draw a rectangle that exactly fits your artboard (or bleed, or whatever you want). If you have smart guides on you should be able to just drag the rectangle over the artboard, if not you can just copy the dimensions and position from the transform panel.

[image: Artboard sized rectangle]

3. Zoom out further than you normally would and draw a large rectangle. Color this rectangle the color you want everything outside the artboard to be, I normally use the same color outside the artboard is normally but you can use any color.

[image: Larger rectangle]

4. Send the larger shape to the back (**Object → Arrange → Send to Back**).

[image: Object>Arrange>Send to Back]

5. Use the Pathfinder panel to subtract the smaller rectangle from the large rectangle.

[image: Pathfinder Subtract]

You can then lock the overlay layer and show or hide the layer whenever you like. Just remember to keep that layer above all the other layers.

[image: Outside artboard hidden]

Comment: You can turn the clipping mask on off the same way just expand the group and click on the eye icon next to clipping mask. It toggles things exactly the same. With added benefit of allowing several pages be closer to each other.

Comment: True, but working on complex layouts with everything under one clipping mask isn't the best. You end up having to change your whole workflow. Only selecting objects via the layers panel or have everything inside the clipping mask in isolation mode. And as far as I'm aware you can't have different layers under one clipping mask? Maybe you can with sublayers?

Comment: If you only want to mask a few shapes, objects that are already grouped, or if it's only a quick temporary preview then a clipping mask is definitely the way to go, but for anything more complex that your still working on (and want to be able to turn the mask on and off whenever you like) this is the best option I've come up with.

Comment: Not everybody has a workflow that is not suited for this. In either case layers are way too limited I use tagged structures.

Comment: I'm sure most people use the selection tool to select objects? Anyway, If having your whole document under a clipping mask doesn't affect your workflow then a clipping mask is definitely easier

Comment: I allways use the direct selection/group selection tool only. I really never use selection tool for anything, as far as im concerned it could be deprecated. Direct selection tool can select trough groups as if they were individual objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33642/discussion-between-joojaa-and-cai-morris).

Comment: Thanks, that kinda solved my issue,

Answer (score 7):

This is a super easy workaround that I've used quite a bit if you want to view what it will look like on the page. I originally learned about it on this group somewhere, but cannot find the original post.

Open the Navigator panel (Window > Navigator) and make the window as big as you like. It will show what the document will look like without the pasteboard.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, have been looking for this for quite a while! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did an Action.

1- **Before** record the action, set Fill and Stroke color to none (transparent).

2- Make a frame using the rectangle tool anywhere.

3- Create a new action.

4- In the dialog I named it "Stroke Artboard" and set Shift F6 (on Mac) as shortcut.

5- Open stroke color panel and set #5d5d5d (dark gray frame background color), click OK.

6- Set stroke weight to 1000pt and Align Stroke to outside.

7- Stop record. Done.

Every time you need, make the rectangle first and run the action.

Answer (score 2):

View - Trim View

this requires 30 characters so i typed this

Comment: Since this question as posted in **2015** you could explain that the option you cite is only available in a specific version. It certainly wasn't there in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

View > Trim View will do that for you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go into presentation mode via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to view only what's inside of the artboard.

Answer (score 0):

To hide all items over an item in a layer, choose the product and also select Things > Conceal > All Artwork Over. To hide all unselected layers, pick Conceal Others from the Layers panel food choice, or Alt‑click (Windows) or Option‑click (Mac OS) the eye symbol for the layer you intend to expose.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out this way:
I set up rectangles outside intersecting the object I want to trim and then with the SHAPE BUILDER TOOL I got rid of the areas I dont need.
It's so Useful!! Believe me [image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the “Rectangle” tool.

Draw a box around the artboard. Make sure the box is on top of everything.

Click on the “Select” menu. Click “Select All” or “Select all on Active Artboard.”

Click on the “Object” menu. Hover over “Clipping Mask” and select “Make.” Everything outside the rectangle will be hidden; however, the information is still available if you release the clipping mask.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND A REAL SOLUTION guys! Just go to View then select "Trim View". It should be in the second panel or the 5th option from the top. Literally hides everything outside of the artboard!

View > Trim View