# How not let the graphics out of the artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I need to setup the illustrator so that I'm not be able to draw anything beyond the artboard, (but I need to keep the duplicates outside the artboard). Like, when I scale an object beyond the artboars's boundaries, only the object's part which is in the artboard is shown..
Didn't get any relevant results on Google, sorry.

Comment: Hi user152435, you want to make it so you physically cannot move objects outside of the artboard? I do not think that is possible. If you want to align anything to the edge of the artboard, then I would use the Align options to get objects to the edge without going over.

Comment: If you're just trying to hide (not visible but still there) objects that fall off of the artboard then I would see this question: [How to hide objects outside artboards in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64832/how-to-hide-objects-outside-artboards-in-illustrator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide objects outside artboards in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64832/how-to-hide-objects-outside-artboards-in-illustrator)

Comment: You **can't** restrict drawing to only an artboard, the best you can do is *hide* what may be outside the artboard, as the duplicate links above suggest.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Please add some screen shots of what you're seeing / trying to accomplish and what you have tried.  It's not very clear what you are asking..

Comment: @Wolff Yeah it 89%ly did, I'm following that method